# Is it possible to get Reddit subcomment json?

Tags: json, api, reddit

I'm looking at the Reddit API and I'm not finding any information on how to pull subcomment JSON.

I want to get a comment and all of its children.

`http://www.reddit.com/r/subreddit/comments/commentid/anytext.json` will get any particular post posted to Reddit (if you put in the subreddit and the id of any particular article), however using this same method to try to get a comment won't work.

Is there anyway to get this data? I'm doing this in Javascript, but this is an endpoint issue above all else, so that doesn't really matter.

Answer (score 1):

Add `.json` to the comment permalink, eg https://www.reddit.com/r/test/comments/3azr6z/doge/cshhtsi.json .